# Accessing arrays and or objects

Tags: php, drupal

**I solved it myself... like 10 minutes later. **

```
$varbgimg = $row->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_slideimage['und'][0]['uri'];
```

Is what I used...

<strike>Hope someone can help me. How can I access **'uri' => 'public://veglo8.jpg'**?</strike>

This is from Drupal and the Views module. If someone could maybe even help me with my ultimate goal, I would appreciate that...

I have a field in Views called **slideimage**. I want to add a *style="background-image:url(**image field URL**);"* to my div. Tried to rewrite the output but it strips the style...

Thanks in advance.

```
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'nid' => '20',
   'node_title' => 'Test 1',
   'field_data_field_slideimage_node_entity_type' => 'node',
   'field_data_body_node_entity_type' => 'node',
   '_field_data' => 
 array (
   'nid' => 
   array (
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'entity' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'vid' => '20',
     'uid' => '1',
     'title' => 'Test 1',
     'log' => '',
     'status' => '1',
     'comment' => '1',
     'promote' => '0',
     'sticky' => '0',
     'nid' => '20',
     'type' => 'test',
     'language' => 'und',
     'created' => '1358336066',
     'changed' => '1358337923',
     'tnid' => '0',
     'translate' => '0',
     'revision_timestamp' => '1358337923',
     'revision_uid' => '1',
     'body' => 
    array (
      'und' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'value' => 'Body text here',
          'summary' => '',
          'format' => 'filtered_html',
          'safe_value' => '
Body text here',
          'safe_summary' => '',
        ),
      ),
    ),
     'field_slideimage' => 
    array (
      'und' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'fid' => '8',
          'alt' => '',
          'title' => '',
          'width' => '624',
          'height' => '390',
          'uid' => '1',
          'filename' => 'veglo8.jpg',
          'uri' => 'public://veglo8.jpg',
          'filemime' => 'image/jpeg',
          'filesize' => '27393',
          'status' => '1',
          'timestamp' => '1358336725',
          'rdf_mapping' =>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `file_create_url` to convert `public://...` to real world URLs.

`$real_url = file_create_url($img_src);`

Comment: Solved it myself. I used your code to convert the URL. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the `pathinfo()` function for this in the past.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

You can apply styles programmatically with this by replacing `user-picture[0]['uri']` with your image url. I think you can even place the whole public:// url in there and it will work just fine as well.

```
THUMBNAIL_STYLE = 'thumbnail'; 

// now get the full image url from the uri and the style
$default_thumbnail = image_style_url($THUMBNAIL_STYLE, $user->picture[0]['uri']);
```

http://drupal.org/node/1425836